# Android gradle build with Jack for Java 8 fails "importing types"

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-jack-and-jill

The build fails with a TypeImportConflictException which fires a LibraryReadingException.

The error log is the following: http://pastebin.com/fZA643Tq

Ive noticed that along with the exceptions there comes this message:
    see property 'jack.import.type.policy' for type collision policy

I've searched for how to use this property but found nothing. Also, the official documentation for jack (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/jackandjill) doesn't help either.